# DataBase Handling Problems - Insertion trouble with PDO

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm developing a website for my university and it include having users and everything around it but i have problem with this code :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function hashSSHA($password) 
{
    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}





function storeUser($name, $email, $password) 
{


    $uuid = uniqid('fss_u', true);
    $hash = hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password =  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $regday = date("Y-m-j");
    $type_user= 'admin';
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3308;dbname=fss-db', 'root', 'nabounanc1');

    echo $encrypted_password ;
    echo  '<br>';

    $query=$db->prepare('INSERT INTO fss_users (unique_id,username,email,password,salt,create_time,type_user) VALUES (:uuid, :name, :email, :encrypted_password, :salt, :regday, :type_user) ');
    $query->bindValue(':uuid', $uuid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':encrypted_password', $encrypted_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':regday', $regday, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':type_user', $type_user, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    $query->execute();


        // check for successful store

    if ($query->execute()) 
    {
        echo $query->rowCount();
        echo  '<br>';
       $result = $query->fetchAll();

        print_r($result);

        // get user details 
        $uid = $db->lastInsertId(); // last inserted id
        $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM fss_users WHERE unique_id = :uid");
        $query->bindValue(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();




        //Message
        $message = "Bienvenue sur FSS Votre inscription a ete accepte pseudo = $email mot de passe = $password !";
        //Titre
        $titre = "Bienvenue sur FSS !";

        mail($email, $titre, $message);  // Mail to the new user 

        // return user details
        //return $query->fetchAll();
        echo 'it\'s good';
        echo  '<br>';

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'error';
        echo  '<br>';
        //return $false;
    }
}
$name = "bachirdiop";
$email = "testing@hotmail.com";
$password = "bachirdiop3";
storeUser($name, $email, $password);
```

Basically this function hash the password given by the user and stores it into a database and if everything is normal it should return the last recorded user but it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: sidenote: is that tick `\`` over to the left of `$salt` supposed to be there; is it part of your real code? it's throwing off syntax highlighting.

Comment: You're doing `INSERT` operation, not `SELECT` operation, why are you doing `->rowCount() and ->fetchAll()`. Just do this, `if($query->execute()){ ...get user details... }`

Comment: btw, don't use `sha1`.

Comment: yes it's a part of my real code the ` is just an error of formating and the syntax highlighting too i'm going to correct it

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: *"yes it's a part of my real code"* I don't understand. Yet you say you'll fix the highlighting. that tick shouldn't be in your working code and if it's part of your working code, it should be throwing you an error about it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what should i use instead of sha1

Comment: Use what @JayBlanchard put up there ;-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php check for errors.

Comment: So what happened now? Is it working? Based on your updated code, you're executing the query two times. And I still don't understand, why are you using `echo $query->rowCount(); $result = $query->fetchAll();`?

Comment: i changed the code but it still does'nt work i have added `echo $query->rowCount(); $result = $query->fetchAll(); ` to do some debugging and know what really happen

Comment: do the size of the password column matter i have a varchar(128) who can help please nothing is working